# CSS - Arrow not lining up

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying tro create a pure CSS arrow with a line like this...

```css
.arrow {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
}

.arrow_line {
 width:2px;
 background:darkblue;
  height:60px;
 margin:auto;
}

.arrow_point {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: darkblue;
 border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
 margin-top: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="arrow_line"></div>
  <div class="arrow_point"></div>
</div>
```

The vertical line never quite seems to line up vertically with the arrow, I have left it slightly adrift in the example to better demonstrate that it is not centered in relation to the arrow.

Is there a better way to create a CSS arrow?

Comment: Why not use the unicode arrows? `↓`

Comment: Why do you think you can center an even number? 
Since the line is only 2px wide, you'll never have it line up perfectly with the tip of the "point".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one element and gradient then you won't have issue with centring:

```css
.arrow {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom right/40px 4px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom right/4px 40px,
    linear-gradient(
    to top right,
    transparent calc(50% - 2px),
    blue        calc(50% - 2px),
    blue        calc(50% + 2px),
    transparent calc(50% + 2px));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
</div>
```

You can also easily adjust the size:

```css
.arrow {
  width:var(--s,80px);
  height:var(--s,80px);
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom right/calc(var(--s,80px)/2) calc(var(--t,2px)*2),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom right/calc(var(--t,2px)*2) calc(var(--s,80px)/2),
    linear-gradient(
    to top right,
    transparent calc(50% - var(--t,2px)),
    blue        calc(50% - var(--t,2px)),
    blue        calc(50% + var(--t,2px)),
    transparent calc(50% + var(--t,2px)));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  margin:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
</div>

<div class="arrow" style="--t:3px;--s:60px">
</div>

<div class="arrow" style="--t:1px;--s:40px">
</div>

<div class="arrow" style="--t:2px;--s:20px">
</div>

<div class="arrow" style="--t:1px;--s:20px">
</div>
```

Comment: That still looks off centered to me when I zoom in, might just be my eyes though!

Comment: @fightstarr20 it depends how much you will zoom :)

Answer (score 2):

Give your line a width which is odd. You used `2px` on the line, and that resulted in the line being slightly off to one side.
I made it `3px` as example.

Or vice versa, make your "point" an even number, which may make more sense, since you'll want the lines to have the same thic<strike>c</strike>kness.

```css
.arrow {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
}

.arrow_line {
 width:2px;
  //width: 3px;
 background:darkblue;
  height:60px;
 margin:auto;
}

.arrow_point {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 26px;
  //height: 25px;
 width: 26px;
  //width: 25px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: darkblue;
 border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
 margin-top: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="arrow_line"></div>
  <div class="arrow_point"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But then the lines have different thicknesses. It would be better to adjust the height/width of `.arrow_point`

Comment: Yes I saw your comment @Turnip and edited it into the answer. Thank you, for your comment

Comment: @TemaniAfif Allrighty, but I really want to honor you, because as soon as I see your name, there's an exceptional good answer to it, with approaches many others didn't use.

Comment: thanks :) but the upvote system or comments should be enough for this ;) we should avoid noises in the answers. I would agree with you for old questions when sometimes the good answer come late and is at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Since you arrow point is 25px wide, it won't line up. Because 25 isn't an even number.
Change it to 24 like below or any other even number.

```css
.arrow {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
}

.arrow_line {
 width:2px;
 background:darkblue;
  height:60px;
 margin:auto;
}

.arrow_point {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 24px;
 width: 24px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: darkblue;
 border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
 margin-top: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="arrow_line"></div>
  <div class="arrow_point"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.arrow {
 position:relative;
 height:30px;
  width:2px;
  background:red;
}

.arrow:after{
position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-65%);
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    bottom: -20%;
    left: 50%;

}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">

</div>
```

working randomly change height width of after

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make two small changes to your code:

1) delete the css for .arrow

2) for .arrow_point change margin-top to margin:-24px auto;

if you want to you can delete the < div  class='arrow' >

simple solutions are best!

```css
.arrow {
 /*position:absolute;
 left:50%;*/
}

.arrow_line {
 width:2px;
 background:darkblue;
  height:60px;
 margin:auto;
}

.arrow_point {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: darkblue;
 border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
 /*margin-top: -24px;*/
  margin:-24px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="arrow_line"></div>
  <div class="arrow_point"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple by using unicode arrow instead of creating it.

```css
.arrow{
  color:red;
  font-size:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">&#x2193;</div>
```